# Need help with my cars music system

Tags: honda, civic, audio

i own a 2012 Honda Civic lx. This trim does not come with Bluetooth. I was wondering if i can use the usb Port to connect "something" that can stream my music from my phone (like Spotify) to my car in a way that a usb with songs on it does. What i mean by that is I'm able to change track using my steering wheel controls. i can also see my music on my info screen. Is there a way i can make this happen. I looked on Amazon and all i could find was audio adapter that plugs into the aux port and work like one as well.

Answer (score 1):

The Civic *should* support media control and info through the USB port - they certainly do if you connect an iPod/iPhone to them through USB.

You don't mention what you phone is but you'll need to make sure it supports not only Advanced Audio Distribution Protocol (A2DP) but also the Bluetooth Audio Video Remote Control Protocol (AVRCP) and importantly you'll need to get a USB Bluetooth dongle that supports that profile as well. This will allow the Civic's sound system to see the connected BT device as if it were a regular USB flash drive with media files on and the controls and info will work as per normal.